# File.ReadLine to add line break after each line in TextBlock

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have am trying to read a text file and have the information displayed in a textblock.  For instance in this part of the code I am using the file.readlines function to find all the IPv4 entries and put them into the textblock. The problem is when I run the code I only see the last IPv4 address and the others are deleted.  I want all the lines to show.  I am sure I am missing something simple.  Here is the code:

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines("c:\temp\logs\pcinfo.txt")
        If line.Contains("IPv4") And line.Contains(":") Then
            TextBlock1.Text = line
        End If
    Next line
```

Comment: @TheBlueDog When I change textblock1.text to textblock.appendtext I get this error "appendtext is not part of system.windows.control.textblock".  Why is that?

Comment: @thebluedog I figured it out. I didn't put the &= in front of textblock1.text

Comment: Sorry fella, ignore that - I missed the WPF tag ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the line to the TextBox not replace what is already in the TextBox. If you want multiple lines, you also need to add newline characters.

```
TextBlock1.Text &= line & vbCrLf
```

Comment: When I change textblock1.text to textblock.appendtext I get this error "appendtext is not part of system.windows.control.textblock".  Any ideas?

Comment: I see my mistake.  I didn't put &= Textblock1.text just =  Reading is fundamental.  Thanks a bunch!